# I am unable to access Hive - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.login

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to launch Hive on my Ubuntu machine (Cloudera installation of Hadoop) and I get this error:

```
hdp@DevBox:/$ hive
Hive history file=/tmp/hdp/hive_job_log_hdp_201304271931_185450475.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.login(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop20Shims.getUGIForConf(Hadoop20Shims.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.setConf(HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthenticator(HiveUtils.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
```

I have tried researching and I can find is this page: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201110.mbox/%3CCAEDqXPFhcA=7OVtprQEALh1GK6N60VPenfjHSwe7Y5UhKqksdA@mail.gmail.com%3E

But I am confused as to what it means? I cannot find anything other than 20.2 Hadoop jars on my machine.

This is my classpath:

```
hdp@DevBox:/$ hadoop classpath
```

/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/conf:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/tools.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/aspectjtools-1.6.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/avro-1.5.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/avro-ipc-1.5.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/avro-mapred-1.5.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/avro-tools-1.5.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/elephant-bird-2.0.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/guava-r09-jarjar.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-0.20.2-cdh3u5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.4.15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jetty-servlet-tester-6.1.26.cloudera.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/junit-4.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/libthrift.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/mockito-all-1.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar

I am thoroughly confused, and not sure how to resolve this.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Which Hive version do you use? Hive might pick up another Hadoop version you expect. Didn't you override HADOOP_HOME in hive-env.sh?

Comment: I am unable to determine the version, the best I can do is view the directory ls -al /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive*.jar which gives me 0.7.1-cdh3u5.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute bin/hive from HIVE_ROOT directory